# Array Programming in Java

Tags: java

This is the Registration Class stored as Registration.java.

```
public class Registration {
    int registrationId;
    double fees;
    int marks;
public void setRegistrationId(int registrationId){
    this.registrationId=registrationId;
}
public int getRegistrationId(){
    return registrationId;
}
public void setFees(double fees){
    this.fees=fees;
}
public double getFees(){
    return fees;
}
public void calculateFees(int marks){
    int discount=0;
    if(marks>=85 && marks<=100)
        discount = 12;
    else if(marks>=75 && marks<=84)
        discount = 7;
    else if(marks>=65 && marks<=74)
        discount = 0;
    else
        System.out.println("You have not passed!");
    fees = fees-(fees*(discount/100.0));
    System.out.println("The discount availed is "+discount+" % and the fees after discount is: "+fees);
}
}
```

Another class called DemoReg1.java which hosts the starter method.

```
public class DemoReg1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int branchList[]={1001,1002,1003,1004,1005};
    double fees[]= {25575,15500,33750,8350,20500};      
    Registration reg = new Registration();
    reg.setRegistrationId(2001);
    int branchId=1002;      
    double fees1=0;
    for(int i=0;i<branchList.length;i++)
    {
        if(branchList[i]==branchId)
        { 
            fees1=fees[i];
            reg.setFees(fees1);
            System.out.println("The Registration ID is:"+reg.getRegistrationId());
            System.out.println("The fees before discount is:"+reg.getFees());
            reg.calculateFees(79);
            break;
        } 
       }
      }
    }
```

The output which I get is:

```
The Registration ID is:2001
The fees before discount is:15500.0
The discount availed is 7 % and the fees after discount is: 14415.0
```

I want to add an 'else' condition which prints out the following statement when the branchId provided(local variable) is say 1006.

```
System.out.println("Invalid branch ID");
```

Where in the code should I add the above statement? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Introduce a boolean variable that is set to true if you found the branch, and check the value of this boolean variable after the loop:

```
boolean branchFound = false;
for(int i=0;i<branchList.length;i++)
{
    if(branchList[i]==branchId)
    { 
        branchFound = true;
        fees1=fees[i];
        reg.setFees(fees1);
        System.out.println("The Registration ID is:"+reg.getRegistrationId());
        System.out.println("The fees before discount is:"+reg.getFees());
        reg.calculateFees(79);
        break;
    } 
   }
  }
}
if (!branchFound) {
    System.out.println("Invalid branch ID");
}
```

You should probably introduce a class (`BranchIdAndFee`) that holds the branchId and the associated fee, instead of using parallel arrays. And you should also use a `Map<Integer, BranchIdAndFee>` to be able to get the information from a branch ID in constant time rather than having to loop.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using an `else` clause, simply set a `boolean` flag, and check it's value after the loop. If it is true, then you know that a valid branch was found. No need for an error message. Otherwise, you've got to output the error message.

```
boolean isValidBranch = false;
// Create a flag.    

for(int i=0;i<branchList.length;i++)
{
    if(branchList[i]==branchId)
    { 
        isValidBranch = true;
        fees1=fees[i];
        reg.setFees(fees1);
        System.out.println("The Registration ID is:"+reg.getRegistrationId());
        System.out.println("The fees before discount is:"+reg.getFees());
        reg.calculateFees(79);
        break;
    } 
   }
```

Then simply check if the flag has been set to true:

```
 if(!isValidBranch)
 {
     // Print out your error message.
 }
```

Comment: A pleasure! Mark one of the answers as correct please. Looks like his was a little better than mine :)

Comment: Yours worked too! So, that great! :-) Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

After the for loop, you can test whether or not the branch ID supplied was valid, for example:

```
int ii;

for (ii = 0 ; ii < branchList.length; ii++)
{
  if (branchList[ii] == branchId)
  {
    // do your calculations
    break;
  }
}

if (ii == branchList.length)
{
  printf("Error: supplied branch ID %d was invalid\n", branchId);
}
```